# Periodical solutions of this system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

We have the system of differential equations:
$$x'=(1+m)y+x(1-(x^2+y^2))(4-(x^2+y^2)),$$
$$y'=-x+y(1-(x^2+y^2))(4-(x^2+y^2)),$$
with $m>0$.

> 1. How do I show that $(0,0)$ is the only (instable) critical point?
> 2. How do I show that there is an $m_0$ such that for $0<m<m_0$ this system has ***TWO*** periodic (not-constant) solutions?

***What I have done so far:*** I wrote the sytem above in polar coordinates:
$$r'=mr\sin\theta\cos\theta+r(1-r^2)(4-r^2),$$
$$\theta'=-1-m\sin^2\theta.$$
But I don't know how this can help me.
For question 2. I must use Poincare-Bendixson, but I don't see how exactly.

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange, and thank you for showing your work so far. To make further progress, eliminate $x$ and $y$ fro the polar form of the equations by using $x = r \cos \theta, y = r \sin \theta$.

Comment: @HansEngler Thank you for welcoming me and thank you for the tip. Could you help me further?

Comment: Consider the second equation. For which $\theta$ could the right hand side be zero if $m > 0$ is assumed?

Comment: @HansEngler Is that possible?

Comment: No, I guess it is not :) since $-1 - m \sin^2 \theta < 0$ for all choices. So what went wrong? You divided by $r$, assuming that $r \ne 0$, at some point, didn't you?

Comment: @HansEngler Yes, because $\theta'=\frac{xy'-yx'}{r^2}$

Comment: therefore that step was illegal. What does that tell you? And how can you turn that into a proof?

Comment: @HansEngler I have no idea to be honest, what exactly is illegal here? Is my expression for $\theta'$ false?

Comment: 1) We know that the origin is an equilibrium point. Polar coordinates work fine on $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ 0 \}$. If there would be additional equilibria, then $\theta'$ would be zero at them. And this never happens for small $m$; 2) To use Poincare-Bendixson theorem, you should construct _trapping region_. When $m = 0$, step a little bit from limit cycles and consider two circles of slightly less and slightly greater radii. They bound an annulus. If you check vector field on them, it points inside the annulus and they are never tangent to boundary of annulus...

Comment: ... If perturbation of vector field is small, then it won't spoil this property ('pointing inside of annulus') -- it's a simple consequence of continuous dependence of vector field with respect to parameter.

Comment: @Evgeny Thank you for your comment, would you mind making an answer out of that?

Comment: Well, I'll try, but not this evening :) giving full answer (IMHO) requires filling some gaps and drawing a nice picture. I like drawing them, but don't have much time today...

Comment: @Evgeny Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all the proof that the origin is the only critical point can be proved following the comments of @Hans Engler. I will skip the details.

For the second question there are possibly other ways to prove this by I will present one that looks appealing to me. Consider the function 
$$V:=r^2=x^2+y^2$$
The time derivative of $V$ is given by 
$$\dot{V}=-2m\: xy+2V(1-V)(4-V)$$
that can be written equivalently as a quadratic form
$$\dot{V}=\left[\matrix{x & y}\right]\left[\matrix{2(1-V)(4-V) & -m\\-m & 2(1-V)(4-V)}\right]\left[\matrix{x \\ y}\right]$$
From the above equation $\dot{V}< 0$ iff
$$(i)\quad 1<V<4\\(ii)\quad m<2(V-1)(4-V)$$
and $\dot{V}>0$ iff
$$(i)\quad 0<V<1\quad or \quad V>4\\(ii)\quad m<2(1-V)(4-V)$$
Note that the maximum value of $2(V-1)(4-V)$ when $V\in(1,4)$ is $4.5$ and is achieved if $V=2.5$. Thus, for $0<m<m_0=4.5$ we have 
$$\dot{V}<0\text{   whenever  } V=2.5$$
Also, if $0<m<m_0=4.5$ then for any $\epsilon\in\left(0,\frac{5-3\sqrt{2}}{2}\right]$ we have that 
$$\dot{V}>0 \text{   whenever  } V=\epsilon$$

This means that if initially $V(0)\in[\epsilon,2.5]$ then $V(t)\in[\epsilon,2.5]$ for all $t\geq 0$. Define now the bounded closed subset of the plane  $R:=\{(x,y)|\epsilon\leq V \leq 2.5\}$. Obviously $R$ does not contain fixed points (the origin) and all trajectories starting in $R$ are confined in $R$. Thus, the Poincare-Bendixson theorem can be directly applied to prove  the existence of a periodic trajectory inside $R$.

Comment: But does this only show that there exists one periodic trajectory? Because I need two

Comment: @LucasGeorge No it only shows that there is at least one. However, as you correctly pointed, plots indicate that there are two. I will try to modify my proof to show this also.

Comment: @LucasGeorge From what I see there is one stable (inner) periodic orbit and one unstable (outer) periodic orbit. Thus one cannot find two different trapping regions because all solutions in the neighborhood of the outer periodic orbit escape either to infinity or towards the inner periodic orbit. Instead a possible approach is to look for two different invariants within the region $R$ I defined above.

Comment: So how do we show this in the proof?